# Why do I get the error 'sqlite3.OperationalError: near "?": syntax error'?

Tags: python, sqlite

I have trouble making a very easy and simple `sqlite3` query. The following code

```
p = ('user',)
cursor.execute("SELECT Guid FROM ? LIMIT 1",p)
```

gives the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "try_Units.py", line 21, in <module>
    cursor.execute("SELECT Guid FROM ? LIMIT 1",p)
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "?": syntax error
```

but I am using the exact syntax as explained in the example [here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/sqlite3.html). So what is wrong this that syntax (python 3.4.0)?

I want to access the attribute 'Guid' from a table named 'user'.

Comment: You should never have to have a dynamic `FROM` clause if your schema is well-normalized and you're not writing an ORM or something similar.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use SQL parameters for object names (such as tables or columns). The whole point of a parameter is to *prevent* values from being interpreted as SQL objects or commands, after all.

Use string formatting here, but *vet your input* if it comes from a user, to prevent SQL injection:

```
p = 'user'
cursor.execute("SELECT Guid FROM {} LIMIT 1".format(p))
```

Comment: I read that answer, but I do not understand the answer. What is the point in introducing the syntax with the question mark if you cannot use it?

Comment: @Alex: you can use it for **values**. A table name is not a value.

Comment: @Alex: With the `?` in place, you are trying to generate the query `SELECT Guid FROM 'user' LIMIT 1`, but you cannot select from a SQL string; `'user'` is a string, not the table named `user`.

Comment: @Alex: no, `Guid` is a column name. `SELECT Guid FROM user WHERE name='foobar'` would be using `'foobar'` as a value (something you can store *in* a database column). So `SELECT Guid FROM user WHERE name=?` would be a valid use of a SQL parameter.

Comment: A value comes from a user input and you normally uses in in the where clause, like this "SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE some_column = ?".

Comment: I understand better. This should be mentioned on the sqlite3 documentation page, I guess this confuses many, many people overreading the word 'value' somewhere in that chapter...

Comment: @Alex: SQL parameters is a concept that applies across all database adapters, so just like the sqlite documentation assumes you know how to use SQL it also assumes you know how SQL parameters work.

Comment: Well, I am still learning. Today the hard way it seems...